# formatting URL parameters using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

First let me show you my .htaccess file code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/public/admin/

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

The code above works fine but what I would like to add to this is when I type the following URL

```
http://localhost/site/public/admin/AccidentDetails/?caseid=12
```

it should change to the following

```
http://localhost/site/public/admin/AccidentDetails/caseid/12/
```

Not good at mode rewriting I would like have your opinion on that, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/public/admin/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

## hide .php extension snippet    
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: it does change the URL to my desired way but it doesn't show the page... the error is `Not Found

The requested URL /AccidentDetails/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: So actual internal URL should be `admin/AccidentDetails.php` OR `admin/AccidentDetails/index.php`?

Comment: it is `admin/AccidentDetails.php` with leading ?caseid=any number

Comment: thank you that works... glad you helped you're a true gentleman Anuhbhav thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

Right below your `RewriteBase` line, add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+?)(?:\.php|)\?caseid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/caseid/([0-9]+)/$ $1?caseid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: error `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log`

Comment: do I have to delete any of my code I've replaced your code with my code under `RewriteBase`

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan I left out a `]`. You don't need to change any of your existing code

Answer (score 1):

add the following code below the `RewriteBase` line

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```